# Theorems on continuous embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X,Y$ be two normed spaces such that $X\hookrightarrow Y$.
Show the following:

1) If $A\subset X$  is closed in $Y$ then $A$ is closed in $X$;

2) If $X, Y$ are Banach spaces if $x_n$ tends weakly to $x \in X$ then $x_n$ tends weakly to $x \in Y$

3)If $X$ is reflexive and $x_n$ is bounded  and weakly convergent to $x \in Y$, then $x \in X$ and $x_n$ converges weakly to $x \in X$.

4) If $X$ is reflexive the unitary closed ball in $X$ is closed in $Y$.

*My definition is: $X \hookrightarrow Y$ if $X \subseteq Y$ and the map $J : X \to Y$ defined as $Jx=x$ is continuous: $||Jx||_Y=||x||_Y \le C||x||_X,\ \forall x \in X$, with $C$ a nonnegative constant. $J$ is assumed to be linear.*

Comment: Well I'm trying to use the definition of weak convergence and continuous embedding but I'm not able to reach the thesis.
The first point seems to me naturally coming because if $A$ equals its closure in Y and $A\subset X \subset Y$ then $A$ equals its closure in X also. But I don't think this is rigorous and I'm not using the hypothesis of continuous embedding...

Comment: what do you mean by Continuous embedding? Whether do you mean that there exists simply an injective continuous map from X to Y or an injective continuous linear map from X to Y.

Comment: My definition is: $X \hookrightarrow Y$ if $X\subseteq Y$ and the map $J:X \rightarrow Y$ defined as $Jx=x $ is continuous: $||Jx||_Y=||x||_Y \leq C ||x||_X \>\>\> \forall x\in X$ with $C$ a nonnegative costant. $J$ assumed to be linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof:

1. If $A$ is closed in $Y$, then $J^{-1}(A)=A$ is closed in $X$ because $J$ is continuous.
2. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$. Now, let $f\in Y^*$. Then $f\circ J\in X^*$. Hence $f(x_n)=(f\circ J)(x_n)$ converges  to $(f\circ J)(x)=f(x)$. Therefore, $(x_n)$  converges weakly to $x$ in $Y$.
3. Since $X$ is reflexive space. Hence $X$ is a Banach space. Also $\parallel x\parallel _Y\leq C\parallel x\parallel _X$. Hence by the Bounded Inverse Theorem, both the norms on $X$ are equivalent. Hence $X$ is a closed convex subset of $Y$. Therefore, $X$ is weakly closed in $Y$. This implies that $x\in X$. Also with the help of Hahn-Banach extension theorem, we can verify that $(x_n)$
   converges weakly to $x$ in $X$.
4. Since $X$ is reflexive, by Banach-Alaoglu theorem, the closed unit ball of $X$ is weakly closed in $X$. Since $X$ is weakly closed in $Y$, the closed unit ball of $X$ is also weakly closed in $Y$. Also the closed unit ball of $X$ is a convex set. This implies that the latter set is also closed in $Y$.